# Test Salesforce data validations without activating them

Tags: validation, salesforce

In ["Validation Rule Considerations,"](http://na8.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/fields_validation_considerations.htm) there's a note:

"A poorly designed validation rule can prevent users from saving valid data. *Make sure you thoroughly test a validation rule before activating it.*"

How do you test a validation rule without it being active?

Answer (score 4):

I believe they're referring to testing it in a [developer](http://www.developerforce.com/events/regular/registration.php?d=70130000000EjHb) or [sandbox](http://www.salesforce.com/platform/cloud-infrastructure/sandbox.jsp) environment first.